# Undo stops wroking after undoing something 5-10 times

Tags: customization

guys.
I am pretty new to Blender and undo is my main tool, but it works really weirdly in Blender in my opinion(at least by default). Sometimes it lets you undo 10 steps, sometimes 20 steps, and sometimes only a few steps. Is something wrong with my settings or what makes undo stop undoing something? It's not a keyboard problem I think as all google searches suggest, because Edit>Undo also stops working.

Comment: Thank you, couldn't find it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to User Preferences(Edit -> Preferences or <kbd>F4</kbd>-><kbd>p</kbd>) to see the setting for Undo. They are in System tab, Memory & Limits panel. Undo might also be limited by the amount of memory your computer has.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time even if the question was answered before!

Comment: I did not check if it was to be honest.